# Couldn't launch Android Emulator on Ubuntu 11.10 - Make sure the SDK directory is properly setup

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, ubuntu-11.10

I just configured eclipse on Ubuntu 11.10 for Android Development.

When i try to launch Emulator it shows me following error.

[image]

Console says:

```
[2012-08-24 22:15:12 - Test two] Android Launch!
[2012-08-24 22:15:12 - Test two] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-24 22:15:12 - Test two] Performing com.project.test.two.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-08-24 22:15:12 - Test two] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'avd14'
[2012-08-24 22:15:12 - Test two] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd14'
[2012-08-24 22:15:12 - Test two] Launch canceled!
```

I also have installed **ARM EABI v7a System image** API level 14 (4.0)
SDK platform, Google APIs and sample SDKs are also installed as per shown in SDK manager.

Android SDK tools: 20.0.3
Android SDK platform-tools 14

How do i tackle it?

Comment: Do you have "emulator" under the tools folder in your Android SDK folder?

Answer (score 1):

run this command in your terminal
chmod +x /sdk/tools/android
It works fine for me for the same problem. Try this.